# advice for tensorflow pix2pix tutorial crashing jupyter notebook and spyder kernels as well as issues running in anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, tensorflow

First time posting here, so please let me know if I've omitted any potentially useful information.

Been trying to run my labmate's script which heavily relies on pix2pix (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) and have been getting loads of issues with NaNs and plots not showing up. Decided to backtrack to see if I could even run the pix2pix tutorial. Tried both spyder and jupyter notebook and the kernels keep crashing at the upsampling step  for the U-net. Also tried running the script in anaconda prompt but kept getting an error:

> 2022-06-14 17:07:25.518674: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild
> TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2022-06-14
> 17:07:26.164546: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1325 MB memory:  ->
> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0,
> compute capability: 6.1 (256, 512, 3) Could not load library
> cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126 Please make sure
> cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll is in your library path!

I made sure that cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll is in my library path (as suggested by previous stackoverflow pages):
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin
and
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDNN\v8.4.0\bin

I have three versions of cudnn (10.1, 11.3, 11.6) and made sure that its in the bin of each of them, just in case.

Heres the script from pix2pix:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
#%%
import tensorflow as tf

import os
import pathlib
import time
import datetime

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython import display  
#%%
dataset_name = "facades"
#%%
_URL = f'http://efrosgans.eecs.berkeley.edu/pix2pix/datasets/{dataset_name}.tar.gz'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=f"{dataset_name}.tar.gz",
    origin=_URL,
    extract=True)

path_to_zip  = pathlib.Path(path_to_zip)

PATH = path_to_zip.parent/dataset_name
#%%
list(PATH.parent.iterdir())
#%%
sample_image = tf.io.read_file(str(PATH / 'train/1.jpg'))
sample_image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(sample_image)
print(sample_image.shape)
#%%
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(sample_image)
#%%
def load(image_file):
  # Read and decode an image file to a uint8 tensor
  image = tf.io.read_file(image_file)
  image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)

  # Split each image tensor into two tensors:
  # - one with a real building facade image
  # - one with an architecture label image 
  w = tf.shape(image)[1]
  w = w // 2
  input_image = image[:, w:, :]
  real_image = image[:, :w, :]

  # Convert both images to float32 tensors
  input_image = tf.cast(input_image, tf.float32)
  real_image = tf.cast(real_image, tf.float32)

  return input_image, real_image
#%%
inp, re = load(str(PATH / 'train/100.jpg'))
# Casting to int for matplotlib to display the images
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(inp / 255.0)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(re / 255.0)
#%%
# The facade training set consist of 400 images
BUFFER_SIZE = 400
# The batch size of 1 produced better results for the U-Net in the original pix2pix experiment
BATCH_SIZE = 1
# Each image is 256x256 in size
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
#%%
def resize(input_image, real_image, height, width):
  input_image = tf.image.resize(input_image, [height, width],
                                method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
  real_image = tf.image.resize(real_image, [height, width],
                               method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)

  return input_image, real_image
#%%
def random_crop(input_image, real_image):
  stacked_image = tf.stack([input_image, real_image], axis=0)
  cropped_image = tf.image.random_crop(
      stacked_image, size=[2, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3])

  return cropped_image[0], cropped_image[1]
#%%
# Normalizing the images to [-1, 1]
def normalize(input_image, real_image):
  input_image = (input_image / 127.5) - 1
  real_image = (real_image / 127.5) - 1

  return input_image, real_image
#%%
@tf.function()
def random_jitter(input_image, real_image):
  # Resizing to 286x286
  input_image, real_image = resize(input_image, real_image, 286, 286)

  # Random cropping back to 256x256
  input_image, real_image = random_crop(input_image, real_image)

  if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
    # Random mirroring
    input_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(input_image)
    real_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(real_image)

  return input_image, real_image
#%%
#this didn't work
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
for i in range(4):
  rj_inp, rj_re = random_jitter(inp, re)
  plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
  plt.imshow(rj_inp / 255.0)
  plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
#%%
def load_image_train(image_file):
  input_image, real_image = load(image_file)
  input_image, real_image = random_jitter(input_image, real_image)
  input_image, real_image = normalize(input_image, real_image)

  return input_image, real_image
#%%
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(PATH / 'train/*.jpg'))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train,
                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
#%%
try:
  test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(PATH / 'test/*.jpg'))
except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError:
  test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(PATH / 'val/*.jpg'))
#test_dataset = test_dataset.map(load_image_test)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
#%%
#downsample
OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 3
#%%
def downsample(filters, size, apply_batchnorm=True):
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, size, strides=2, padding='same',
                             kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False))

  if apply_batchnorm:
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())

  return result
#%%
down_model = downsample(3, 4)
down_result = down_model(tf.expand_dims(inp, 0))
print (down_result.shape)
#%%
**#upsample**
def upsample(filters, size, apply_dropout=False):
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, size, strides=2,
                                    padding='same',
                                    kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                    use_bias=False))

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  if apply_dropout:
      result.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())

  return result
#%%
up_model = upsample(3, 4)
up_result = up_model(down_result)
print (up_result.shape)
#%%
def Generator():
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3])

  down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 64)
    downsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 128)
    downsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 256)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 1, 1, 512)
  ]

  up_stack = [
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 1024)
    upsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 512)
    upsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 256)
    upsample(64, 4),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 128)
  ]

  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(OUTPUT_CHANNELS, 4,
                                         strides=2,
                                         padding='same',
                                         kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                         activation='tanh')  # (batch_size, 256, 256, 3)

  x = inputs

  # Downsampling through the model
  skips = []
  for down in down_stack:
    x = down(x)
    skips.append(x)

  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
  for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
    x = up(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, skip])

  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
#%%
generator = Generator()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(generator, show_shapes=True, dpi=64)
#%%
gen_output = generator(inp[tf.newaxis, ...], training=False)
plt.imshow(gen_output[0, ...])
#%%
LAMBDA = 100
#%%
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
#%%
def generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target):
  gan_loss = loss_object(tf.ones_like(disc_generated_output), disc_generated_output)

  # Mean absolute error
  l1_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(target - gen_output))

  total_gen_loss = gan_loss + (LAMBDA * l1_loss)

  return total_gen_loss, gan_loss, l1_loss
#%%
def Discriminator():
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

  inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3], name='input_image')
  tar = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3], name='target_image')

  x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([inp, tar])  # (batch_size, 256, 256, channels*2)

  down1 = downsample(64, 4, False)(x)  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 64)
  down2 = downsample(128, 4)(down1)  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 128)
  down3 = downsample(256, 4)(down2)  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 256)

  zero_pad1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(down3)  # (batch_size, 34, 34, 256)
  conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 4, strides=1,
                                kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                use_bias=False)(zero_pad1)  # (batch_size, 31, 31, 512)

  batchnorm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)

  leaky_relu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(batchnorm1)

  zero_pad2 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(leaky_relu)  # (batch_size, 33, 33, 512)

  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 4, strides=1,
                                kernel_initializer=initializer)(zero_pad2)  # (batch_size, 30, 30, 1)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp, tar], outputs=last)
#%%
discriminator = Discriminator()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(discriminator, show_shapes=True, dpi=64)
#%%
disc_out = discriminator([inp[tf.newaxis, ...], gen_output], training=False)
plt.imshow(disc_out[0, ..., -1], vmin=-20, vmax=20, cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.colorbar()
#%%
def discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output):
  real_loss = loss_object(tf.ones_like(disc_real_output), disc_real_output)

  generated_loss = loss_object(tf.zeros_like(disc_generated_output), disc_generated_output)

  total_disc_loss = real_loss + generated_loss

  return total_disc_loss
#%%
generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-4, beta_1=0.5)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-4, beta_1=0.5)
#%%
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                                 discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                                 generator=generator,
                                 discriminator=discriminator)
#%%
def generate_images(model, test_input, tar):
  prediction = model(test_input, training=True)
  plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

  display_list = [test_input[0], tar[0], prediction[0]]
  title = ['Input Image', 'Ground Truth', 'Predicted Image']

  for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    plt.title(title[i])
    # Getting the pixel values in the [0, 1] range to plot.
    plt.imshow(display_list[i] * 0.5 + 0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()
#%%
for example_input, example_target in test_dataset.take(1):
  generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)
#%%
log_dir="logs/"

summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(
  log_dir + "fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
#%%
@tf.function
def train_step(input_image, target, step):
  with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    gen_output = generator(input_image, training=True)

    disc_real_output = discriminator([input_image, target], training=True)
    disc_generated_output = discriminator([input_image, gen_output], training=True)

    gen_total_loss, gen_gan_loss, gen_l1_loss = generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output)

  generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_total_loss,
                                          generator.trainable_variables)
  discriminator_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss,
                                               discriminator.trainable_variables)

  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients,
                                          generator.trainable_variables))
  discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_gradients,
                                              discriminator.trainable_variables))

  with summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('gen_total_loss', gen_total_loss, step=step//1000)
    tf.summary.scalar('gen_gan_loss', gen_gan_loss, step=step//1000)
    tf.summary.scalar('gen_l1_loss', gen_l1_loss, step=step//1000)
    tf.summary.scalar('disc_loss', disc_loss, step=step//1000)
#%%
def fit(train_ds, test_ds, steps):
  example_input, example_target = next(iter(test_ds.take(1)))
  start = time.time()

  for step, (input_image, target) in train_ds.repeat().take(steps).enumerate():
    if (step) % 1000 == 0:
      display.clear_output(wait=True)

      if step != 0:
        print(f'Time taken for 1000 steps: {time.time()-start:.2f} sec\n')

      start = time.time()

      generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)
      print(f"Step: {step//1000}k")

    train_step(input_image, target, step)

    # Training step
    if (step+1) % 10 == 0:
      print('.', end='', flush=True)


    # Save (checkpoint) the model every 5k steps
    if (step + 1) % 5000 == 0:
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)
#%%
#%load_ext tensorboard
#%tensorboard --logdir {log_dir}
#%%
fit(train_dataset, test_dataset, steps=40000)
#%%
#tensorboard dev upload --logdir {log_dir}
#%%
display.IFrame(
    src="https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/lZ0C6FONROaUMfjYkVyJqw",
    width="100%",
    height="1000px")
#%%
#ls {checkpoint_dir}
#%%
# Restoring the latest checkpoint in checkpoint_dir
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
#%%
# Run the trained model on a few examples from the test set
for inp, tar in test_dataset.take(5):
  generate_images(generator, inp, tar)
#%%
```

Other OS/software/GPU details:
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 driver 511.79
Matlab 2021a
anaconda 3 (but have a 3.7 environment)
Windows 10, Build 19044.1706 64-bit

I'm not sure where I may be going wrong- and have tried loads of different versions of tensorflow-gpu, tensorflow, keras, spyder, jupyter notebook, matplotlib, etc. in different environments. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: edit: please ignore the specification that I'm using python 3.7 in the env.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to install multiple `cuDNN` versions. Please install specific CUDA and cuDNN versions compatible to the installed python and Tensorflow version in your Anaconda environment as mentioned in below [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) and set the path to the same folder.

[image]

Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for more details on GPU setup.